# Prefill form inputs by id via PHP but without using echo inside the HTML of the form

Tags: php, forms, joomla, echo

I need to prefill form inputs on a page but I cannot use echo inside the HTML of the form. All inputs have unique ID's and so far I have this code. By the way this is a page inside the Joomla CMS.

```php
$user_id = $_GET['findId'];
$user = \JFactory::getUser($user_id);
echo $user->email;
```

The above echo is just to see if the code was actually working and it is.

I have been searching SO and Google to get an answer but I keep finding these answers:

```html
<input type="text" id="hello" name="hello" value="<?php echo $hello; ?>">
```

How can I achieve the same but without using the echo statement inside the HTML?

What should I change in the below code to achieve this:

```php
$user_id = $_GET['findId'];
$user = \JFactory::getUser($user_id);
$hello.value = $user->email;
```

Comment: Why the requirement to not use `echo`? Is `print` allowed? Or `<?= $hello ?>`? Does Joomla have a templating engine you could use?

Comment: $kerbh0lz no print or anything else within the HTML is not allowed I can't touch it. Which sound strange I know but it needs to be outside the HTML and inside the PHP code as shown above. And I am not sure if what I request is possible at all as I can't find any answers for it. I am basically looking for the php version of jquery's `$('#hello').val($user->email;)`

Comment: Maybe `$form->data['hello'] = 'world';` will do it. Sorry, I don't know Joomla.

Comment: @kerbh0lz Thanks for helping. And for pointing the $form part out that was an error I left in which I removed now as I completely forgotten about it.

Comment: Can you use Javascript?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner Yes I can use Javascript on the page.

Comment: Please post your Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  By speaking to an audience with specific expertise in the CMS, you are more likely to receive support that avoids hacky solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be a solution?

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="hello" name="hello">
```

**JS**

```
var inputfield = document.getElementById("hello");
inputfield.setAttribute('value', '<?=$hello?>');
```

Comment: This could work and is a valid suggestion. I am however keeping the question open hoping for a pure PHP solution. Thank you for your answer!